# How can I replace text with element in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have following xml:

```
<div>foo 123 <span id=123>bar</span> baz</div>
```

And I would like to wrap 123 with `a` element:

```
<div>foo <a>123</a> <span id=123>bar</span> baz</div>
```

**What I tried?**

1) I cannot make a replacement on InnerXml of div element like:

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml("<div>foo 123 <span id='123'>bar</span> baz</div>");

var xmlElement = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
xmlElement.InnerXml = xmlElement.InnerXml.Replace("123", "<a>123</a>");
```

It will result into invalid xml:

> System.Xml.XmlException : '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid
>   attribute character. Line 1, position 26.

2) Also it doesn't let me to replace InnerXml of 1st node inside div element like:

```
var childNode = xmlDocument.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0];
childNode.InnerXml = childNode.InnerXml.Replace("123", "<a>123</a>");
```

Because:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot set the 'InnerXml' for the
>   current node because it is either read-only or cannot have children.

3) I could possibly change 1st Text node to get rid of "123 ", insert new element with 123 after text node. and insert new text node after the element with 123 (with remaining white-space). However it doesn't let me to create a new instance of XmlText.

Comment: I think, Before xml doument load, replace the value, it work. Because inside Tags are there that is reason it cann't  replace the values.

Comment: What do you want to process with id="123"? because if you replace all 123 to <a>123</a> then the span element will be invalid xml format: "<span id=\"<a>123</a>\">bar</span> "

Comment: @SaravanakumarNatarajan thank you for your response, however if I will simply replace 123, then xml will become invalid. Also I want to solve this using XmlDocument.

Comment: @NhanPhan want 123 to be replaced only in text.

Comment: @Vladimirs, Using Regex operation, will remove only inside tag text value. It is possible in regex.

Comment: @SaravanakumarNatarajan yes, I know, thank you. Please note - this question is about XmlDocument and I want to solve this using XmlDocument class

Comment: @Vladimirs, Thanks for your reply. I will try it any thing got let u know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code. But remember that this code still needs some work to secure from exceptions:

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml("<div>foo 123 <span id='123'>bar</span> baz</div>");

// get first child and the ID from second child
var firstChild = xmlDocument.FirstChild.FirstChild;
var id = firstChild.NextSibling.Attributes[0].Value;

// remove the ID from the text
firstChild.Value = firstChild.Value.Replace(id, "");

// create the node and set it's inner text to ID
var node = xmlDocument.CreateNode("element", "a", "");
node.InnerText = id;

// append created element to XML
xmlDocument.FirstChild.InsertAfter(node, firstChild);
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I will mark this as answer, it turns out that you can create Text node by `xmlDocument.CreateNode("text", "", "")`. So I can go with 3) at least now I know how to create text node.

Comment: @Vladimirs Happy I could help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect solution, but you can replace "123" text by Regex:

```
            var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml("<div>foo 123 <span id='123'>bar</span> baz</div>");

            var xmlElement = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
            xmlElement.InnerXml = Regex.Replace(xmlElement.InnerXml, "([^\"]123[^\"])", " <a>123</a>");
```

Comment: Thank you, this also works but this is a bit hacky. I was looking to utilise only XmlDocument functionality without regex.

Comment: RegEx is not best option for dealing with XMLs.